# Scrapy - Select specific link based on text

Tags: python, web-crawler, scrapy

This should be easy but I'm stuck.

```
<div class="paginationControl">
  <a href="/en/overview/0-All_manufactures/0-All_models.html?page=2&amp;powerunit=2">Link Text 2</a> | 
  <a href="/en/overview/0-All_manufactures/0-All_models.html?page=3&amp;powerunit=2">Link Text 3</a> | 
  <a href="/en/overview/0-All_manufactures/0-All_models.html?page=4&amp;powerunit=2">Link Text 4</a> | 
  <a href="/en/overview/0-All_manufactures/0-All_models.html?page=5&amp;powerunit=2">Link Text 5</a> |   

<!-- Next page link --> 
  <a href="/en/overview/0-All_manufactures/0-All_models.html?page=2&amp;powerunit=2">Link Text Next ></a>
</div>
```

I'm trying to use Scrapy (Basespider) to select a link based on it's Link text using:

```
nextPage = HtmlXPathSelector(response).select("//div[@class='paginationControl']/a/@href").re("(.+)*?Next")
```

For example, I want to select the next page link based on the fact that it's text is "Link Text Next". Any ideas?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Use `a[contains(text(),'Link Text Next')]`:

```
nextPage = HtmlXPathSelector(response).select(
    "//div[@class='paginationControl']/a[contains(text(),'Link Text Next')]/@href")
```

Reference: Documentation on the XPath [contains](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/#function-contains) function

---

PS. Your text `Link Text Next` has a space at the end. To avoid having to include that space in the code:

```
text()="Link Text Next "
```

I think using `contains` is a bit more general while still being specific enough.

Comment: Thanks guys. I used the suggestion by @unutbu and it worked perfectly.

Comment: So there is no CSS selector way to do this?

Answer (score 6):

You can use the following XPath expression:

```
//div[@class='paginationControl']/a[text()="Link Text Next"]/@href
```

This selects the `href` attributes of the link with text `"Link Text Next"`.

See [XPath string functions](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/#section-String-Functions) if you need more control.

Answer (score 1):

Your xpath is selecting the href not the text in the `a` tag.  It doesn't look from your example like the href has `next` in it, so you can't find it with an RE.